# Elasticsearch - Return nested values in format

Tags: elasticsearch

How can i make elasticsearch return nested values in format of hits `{value1:..., value2..., value3..., etc..}`

```
This is my request:
{
  "_source": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "photo", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "photo.hello": "true"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }, 
            "inner_hits" : {}
          }
        }
      ]
}}}
```

`{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.2231436,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": ".3eautiful",
        "_type": "profile",
        "_id": "6UAaCls5iSgavEtFE2qMX902Xmb2",
        "_score": 1.2231436,
        "inner_hits": {
          "photo": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1.2231436,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": ".3eautiful",
                  "_type": "profile",
                  "_id": "6UAaCls5iSgavEtFE2qMX902Xmb2",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "photo",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.2231436,
                  "_source": {
                    "hello": "true",
                    "i_am_superCOOL": "true",
                    "xoxox": "true",
                    "id": "-KSDRx5BN54JHitoq7Wb"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": ".3eautiful",
        "_type": "profile",
        "_id": "KDFbeXrOedf7b6NVRGMO0HDIFgx1",
        "_score": 1.2231436,
        "inner_hits": {
          "photo": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": 1.2231436,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": ".3eautiful",
                  "_type": "profile",
                  "_id": "KDFbeXrOedf7b6NVRGMO0HDIFgx1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "photo",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 1.2231436,
                  "_source": {
                    "alahu": "true",
                    "hello": "true",
                    "same": "true",
                    "smukais": "true",
                    "id": "-KSDJzyUC_N5je-cR2aT"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": ".3eautiful",
                  "_type": "profile",
                  "_id": "KDFbeXrOedf7b6NVRGMO0HDIFgx1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "photo",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.2231436,
                  "_source": {
                    "hello": "true",
                    "same": "true",
                    "selfyyy": "true",
                    "superSexy": "true",
                    "id": "-KPn4p7spS8NO7IVSLdF"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

I am using 2 dimension dynamic attribute search, the problem with this approach is that the result's can be 20 from 1 user, but i need to make it propriety based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sticked to the same format.